Power BI Map Visual Bubbles Disappear After Adding Legend or Bubble Size Field
I am using Latitude/Longitude coordinates to plot location points on a map. The bubbles appear fine when just the Lat & Long fields are input into the Power BI normal Map visual. However, when I try to add a field - which is a simple count measure - into the Bubble Size field, or add a unique type field into Legend to show different colours, every single bubble immediately disappears, with no error message from Power BI as well. Any idea on why this happens? I only have 500+ data points. Same thing happens with ARCGis maps, I tried Filled Map but it doesn't really serve my purpose, and for Azure Map, I don't have access to it yet. How do I fix this with the normal Map Visual? Thank you.



